# How to get IRI of an Ontology in OWL

Tags: java, owl

In previous versions of OWL-API, obtaining iri from ontology was done through

```
ontology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI();
```

But now getOntologyIRI() returns Optional and therefore the above code does not work. Is there any method to retrieve Ontology's IRI?

[image: Error image]

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just call `get()` on the returned `Optional`?

Comment: This error is showing "The method getOntologyIRI() from the type OWLOntologyID refers to the missing type Optional." So get() is method is not coming up in suggestions also.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java 8 and not an earlier version?

Comment: Yes. 100% sure.

Comment: Um... I'm really not sure what to tell you then.  Your IDE is clearly not able to find `Optional`, which should be in rt.jar in your jdk.  If you're using eclipse, perhaps you've got  JDK Compliance turned down to an earlier version?

Comment: That is not an issue. Now this error is showing up "The type com.google.common.base.Optional cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: Aha!  Your problem is that you've got a naming conflict between `com.google.common.base.Optional` and `java.util.Optional`.  Fix your imports, or use a temp variable with a fully-qualified type of `java.util.Optional`, and call `get()` on *it*.

Comment: Ensure all owlapi dependencies are on the classpath. Version 4 uses Guava Optional, version 5 uses java 8 and moved to the standard Optional class

Comment: Kumar Rohit: a) use Maven and use only one version of OWL API (either 4 or 5, not both - this also holds for other libs that you import then, especially reasoners) or b)   use only one version of OWL API with all it's dependencies